# How to use a defined datagridview cell more than one times in same datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am creating a datagridview for my application. Instead of using column definition, I am defining the cells and adding them to datagridview.

My Datagridview will looks like this.

[image]

I defined datagridviewComboboxCell for MaxVal and MinVal once.

when i tried adding these cells to my dgv, i am getting the following error.

***Cell provided already belongs to a grid. This operation is not valid.***

How can i solve this?

Here is my code:

```
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell Max = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell Min = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        Max.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "80", "90", "100" });
        dataGridView1[1, 1] = Max;
        dataGridView1[2, 1] = Max;
        dataGridView1[3, 1] = Max;
        dataGridView1[4, 1] = Max;
        dataGridView1[5, 1] = Max;
        dataGridView1[6, 1] = Max;
        Min.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "80", "90", "100" });
        dataGridView1[1,2] = Min;
        dataGridView1[2, 2] = Min;
        dataGridView1[3, 2] = Min;
        dataGridView1[4, 2] = Min;
        dataGridView1[5, 2] = Min;
        dataGridView1[6, 2] = Min;
    }
```

Also please let me know if threr is any better way of creating this DGV..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
dataGridView1[1, 1] = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)Max.Clone();
```

And I think you should use `for` loop here instead of 12 identical lines of code...